# How to Select all data where the condition are between the same date?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have stored procedure with parameters `@firstDate` and `@lastDate` I'm also have a table named `Products` with fields `id`, `productName`, `status` and `orderDate`.

I want to get the data from `orderDate` with `BETWEEN` condition.
 I've tried this syntax :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_Order
(
  @firstDate    DATETIME,
  @lastDate     DATETIME
)
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT
     productName,
     orderDate
  FROM
     Products
  WHERE
     orderDate BETWEEN @firstDate AND @lastDate
     AND status = 'Active'
  GROUP BY
     productName,
     orderDate
  ORDER BY
     orderDate
END
```

This is the sample data that I've inserted into my table

[image]

When I'm add the same date, e.g '2015-10-12' for `@firtDate` and `@lastDate` it's shows nothing, and when I'm add '2015-10-10' for `@firstDate` and '2015-10-12' for `@lastDate` it's only shows list of products from date '2015-10-10'.

How could this happen? And what's the right syntax for this?

Thanks for answers.

Comment: and? Are you getting any errors or incorrect data?

Comment: I'd lose the `GROUP BY` altogether since you aren't using any aggregation functions and replace it with `DISTINCT`.

Comment: @ehh oh, lol, my bad! already updated

Comment: Please, read how `BETWEEN` works https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187922.aspx

Comment: Or, read how `BETWEEN` doesn't work https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common

Comment: in your proc add one day in @lastDate then subtract 1 second

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are looking for dates on a given day using datetime or datetime2 datatype, the search condition should be between the 1st nanosecond of the day and the 1st of the next day.

This is the best option in order to avoid lost of accuracy or dates being round up or down.

It is also best to use the `DATE` data type if you don't need the time part. You can always cast it back to datetime.

If I follow your example and look for `2015-10-12`, you are doing:

```
orderDate between '2015-10-12 00:00:00.000' AND '2015-10-12 00:00:00.000'
orderDate >= '2015-10-12 00:00:00.000' AND orderDate <= '2015-10-12 00:00:00.000'
```

When it should use:

set @firstDate = '2015-10-12 00:00:00.000'
   set @lastDate = '2015-10-13 00:00:00.000'

As it is explain on the [BETWEEN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187922.aspx) page:

> BETWEEN returns TRUE if the value of test_expression is greater than or equal to the value of begin_expression and less than or equal to the value of end_expression.

The BETWEEN function is similar to:

```
orderDate BETWEEN @firstDate AND @lastDate
orderDate >= @firstDate AND orderDate <= @lastDate
```

You will end up with value for '2015-10-12 00:00:00.000' as well.

It also explain what to do in the Remarks section:

> To specify an exclusive range, use the greater than (>) and less than operators (<).

You therefore have to use:

```
orderDate >= @firstDate AND orderDate < @lastDate
```

Since you want days between `@firstDate` and `@lastDate` and including these values, the best option is

```
orderDate >= @firstDate AND orderDate < DATEADD(day, 1, @lastDate)
```

Still with `@firstDate` and `@lastDate` equal to `2015-10-12`, the query will search for:

```
orderDate >= `2015-10-12` AND orderDate < DATEADD(day, 1, `2015-10-12`)
orderDate >= '2015-10-12 00:00:00.000' AND orderDate < '2015-10-13 00:00:00.000'
```

Finally, you will also find a lot of good thing in the answers of this question: [Why does my query search datetime not match?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/108287/why-does-my-query-search-datetime-not-match/112956#112956)

Comment: This is the best explanation, I get it now, thank you so much sir!